# Turn on computer from motherboard

Tags: motherboard, remote-access, desktop-computer

I have a computer with **asus p8z77-v lx** motherboard and **zalman z9 plus** miditower.

The *power on* and *reset* buttons doesn't work (control panel cables are *broken*). Also on pc there are no installed software for remote turning.

Please tell me, is it possible (and how) to turn on computer (ie to turn on **asus p8z77-v lx**)?

Comment: Your motherboard based on photos of it does not have this capability.  You can try pressing the MemOK button but I doubt that will turn it on.  I suggest you just fix the cables honestly.

Comment: Thanks. There are 4 cables for power on button (all of they are breaked). Does scheme for zalman z9 plus with their explanation exist? I don't want bring comuter to service, because in last time they destroyed my power unit.

Comment: Can you give link on power button with 2-pin PWR_SW please?

Comment: I cannot do that.  I am not sure the reason the answer that was submitted was deleted, I personally wouldn't do it, but it did provide some important information.

Comment: NOT RECOMMENDED but see http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/ASUS%20P8Z77-V%20LX%20Intel%207%20Series%20Motherboard%20Manual.pdf

Answer (score 4):

**Warning! Dangerous!**

1. Buy new ATX 2pin cable for example [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/ATX-PC-Computer-Motherboard-Power-Cable-Switch-On-Off-Reset-Computer-Replacement-/360774703348).
2. **Unplug the electrical cord from the socket.**
3. Open the chassis.
4. Replace the old cable with a new one. The cable should be connected to PWR and Ground pins.
5. **Close the chassis**

Here is a screenshot from [datasheet](http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/ASUS%20P8Z77-V%20LX%20Intel%207%20Series%20Motherboard%20Manual.pdf) where you should connect the cable: 
[image: power button]

Comment: Good answer.  This gets him the ability to solve the actual problem.  Starting your computer with a metal screwdriver every single time just sounds like a horrible idea to me ;-)

Comment: @Oleg, if this post helps, remember to upvote and or accept it (check the tick)

Answer (score 2):

You need to do a short circuit with a piece of metal between the pins where your power button is plugged in on your motherboard. Once it starts, enter bios and set it so You can turn it on from keyboard.

**Be very careful not to touch anything else!**

Comment: Did you manage to solve the problem? Do You have any other question? If it is solved, please accept the solution that You find the best.